# Ruby 2.6.3 Install fail on Mac

Tags: ruby, terminal, failed-installation

I want to proceed to install Ruby 2.6.3 on my Macbook with this :

`rvm use ruby --install --default`

The output I am receiving is :

```
"ruby-2.6.3 - #extracting ruby-2.6.3 to /Users/.rvm/src/ruby-2.6.3.....
ruby-2.6.3 -     #configuring......................................................|
ruby-2.6.3 - #post-configuration.
ruby-2.6.3 - 
#compiling........................................................|
Error running '__rvm_make -j4',
please read /Users/.rvm/log/1564427981_ruby-2.6.3/make.log"

****There has been an error while running make. Halting the installation.
Gemset '' does not exist, 'rvm ruby-2.6.3 do rvm gemset create ' first, or 
append '--create'.****
```

I tried to reinstall gem and ruby but it is the same

Have you got an idea please ?

Thanks you guys

Comment: Seeing `Gemset '' does not exist` with an empty string suggests RVM is in some weird state.

Comment: What do you suggest ?

Comment: Switch gemsets. Reset RVM. [Possibly use `rbenv`](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv).

Comment: Ok i try with rbenv

Comment: Have you simply run `rvm install 2.6.3` followed by `rvm --default use 2.6.3`?

Comment: Yes, i implode it and install it again, same prob'

Comment: I remove RVM and take RBENV and it's working ! Thank you tadman !
For the next step, i follow this tutorial https://gorails.com/setup/osx/10.14-mojave#homebrew

in response to Cary request ;)